# Radial Menu Issue in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've produced a radial menu prefab in Unity that self-adjusts the spacing between buttons. I've included this radial menu in my unit prefabs so players can select from available movement options for each of their units.

The menu looks perfect for objects that are oriented straight, but despite the menu being a child object, it does not rotate to match its parent. The buttons do rotate into the correct orientation, but the radial menu itself defaults to it's original setting: placing the buttons in a 180 arc that originates at -90 degrees.

```
public void SetMenu()
{
        
    float angle = -180 / (childButtons.Count - 1) * Mathf.Deg2Rad; //180 is the total degree range our buttons will fill. Negative to put the buttons beneath our ship. Count -1 because we want the distance of the gaps between buttons.

    for (int i = 0; i < childButtons.Count; i++) //For each button...
    {

        float xpos = Mathf.Cos(angle * i) * buttonDistance; //Make coordinates along an angle increment depending on the total number of buttons to...
        float zpos = Mathf.Sin(angle * i) * buttonDistance;

        childButtons[i].transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + xpos, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + zpos); //Place the button
    }
}
```

[image: Correct orientation around a vertical unit]

[image: Incorrect orientation around a rotated unit]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like there is more code involved you didn't show here .. in general wouldn't it be easier to have one menu parent and let the children arrange themselves in local space? This way they wouldn't even have to care about the parent's orientation

Comment: Is this menu made of Sprites or UI Images? If it is Sprite, you can just make them all child of the plane, and they will follow their parent' rotation. Otherwise, just parent the Images to a common parent and and rotate the parent.

Comment: To clarify: The hierarchy I'm using is Unit -> Canvas -> Canvas (this is where the above function lives) -> Buttons. buttonDistance is 10.

My goal is to be able to run the above function regularly after reducing and increasing the amount of buttons on the fly, placing them equidistant in an 180 degree arc below the unit regardless of the total number. Was hoping to solve it programatically rather than creating a ton of UI elements in the right orientation.

Not sure why it places them based on world angles rather than based on the parents orientation.

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

rotating parent affect to children's rotation.
if you want to sustain it's original rotation then you should rotate them opposite from parent.

But there is more easy and clear way to fix it.

Make an empty object and make it child of ship, parent of buttons.
and just rotate it reverse from parent ship.
when you using this method, you don't need to re-position child button with polar-coordinate converting.

(empty object's local position should be (0,0,0))

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adjusting localPosition rather than setting global. Earlier attempts at localPosition adjustment appeared to fail because the scale difference is massive and UI elements don't use the z axis. buttonDistance needed to be 20X it's original setting to produce the same results at localPosition and now everything is orienting correctly.

New code is:

```
public void SetMenu()
{
    
    float angle = -180 / (childButtons.Count - 1) * Mathf.Deg2Rad; //-180 is the total degree range our buttons will fill. -1 because we want the distance of the gaps between buttons.

    for (int i = 0; i < childButtons.Count; i++) //For each button...
    {
        float xpos = Mathf.Cos(angle * i) * buttonDistance; //Make coordinates along an angle increment depending on the total number of buttons to...
        float ypos = Mathf.Sin(angle * i) * buttonDistance;

        childButtons[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x + xpos, transform.localPosition.y + ypos, transform.localPosition.z); //Place the button
    }

}
```